# How can I insert new early steps (tasks) in the installation process?

Tags: distributions

I would like to insert a new step (task) in the installation process before the **Verify requirements** is run. This because the form with options I want in it is part of the requirements verification step.

Unfortunately there seems to be no hook for that. [hook_install_tasks](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_install_tasks/7) is appending new steps at the end, while [hook_install_tasks_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_install_tasks_alter/7) allow me to alter the default core steps.

While I probably could modify the **Choose language** step, it doesn't feel like an elegant solution as the form I want to add has nothing to do with language.

Is there no such option available?

Comment: Actually, with `hook_install_tasks_alter()` you can also add new tasks, in the same way `hook_form_alter()` allows you to add new form fields to a form.

Comment: Oh, that's great. You don't happen to know a distribution that does this that I can have a look at?

Comment: I was looking for that, but I didn't find a distribution that changes the installation steps.

Comment: The best I've found so far is http://drupal.org/project/demo_profile that does some tricks early on.

Comment: I answered a similar question here. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26460/how-to-hide-set-up-database-step-in-a-installation-profile

Basically you want hook_install_tasks_alter. drupal's hook_form_alter doesnt work in the install process (see my comments in my Gist) so you'll have to build your page's form with your own form function and validation/submit handlers.